# css flip animation not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css

My css flip animation is working perfectly in chrome but not working in mozilla firefox. I am wondering why even though i have provided the moz- prefix.It is working perfectly in microsoft edge even.Can you please help me? I am unable to figure out the problem.. .. . I have edited the question and added the html part as well. please have a look at it.

styles.css

```
   .flip-container {
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-o-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;

  /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
}

  .flip-container:hover .flipper,  
 .flip-container.hover .flipper {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 220px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

-o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

 .front {
  /*background: url(/web/images/movies.jpeg) 0 0 no-repeat;*/
  z-index: 2;
}
 #background1{
  background: url(/web/images/movies.jpeg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
 }

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* background: #f8f8f8; */
  /* background: url(/web/images/paytm.png) 0 0 no-repeat; */
  }
```

html. .. . ..

```
   <div style="text-align:center" class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="flipper" style="text-align:center">
                    <div class="front">
                        <img src="/web/images/gk.jpg"  alt="" /> 
                        <h2 id="play" style="text-align-last: center">GENERAL KNOWLEDGE</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                    <a href="/pksGK">
                    <img src="/web/images/pks.png"  alt="" /> 
                    <h2 id="play" style="text-align-last: center">blah</h2>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you add HTML code too?

Comment: `-moz-` and `-o-`prefixes are not needed these days. Gecko- and Presto-based browsers that don't understand standard unprefixed syntax aren't used by any significant percent of the users anymore. These lines of code only make the debugging harder. In general, you shouldn't add all the prefixes manually, there are automatic tools like Autoprefixer for this.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn can you help me wh this flip animation is still not working in mozilla?